# tableviewcell in IOS5 issue, can't get tabviewcell sender event

Tags: objective-c, ios5, tableview

my code run in ios4, is fine. when it run in ios5, something issue happend.
a tableview include custom cell. the cell include two button, when it run in ios, tableview can got cell button event. but in ios5, tableview can't got cell button event.
I am not sure what's wrong. please help.
thanks!
the code example is:
tableview code is:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if ([self.selectType selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
         testCell *cell = (testCell *)[tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell"];
        cell.dataSource = [self.testCellData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

tableviewcell code is:

```
- (IBAction)showMap:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"showMap");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"testCellSelected" object:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [dataSource valueForKey:@"ll"],nil]];    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you got a reusable cell:

```
testCell *cell = (testCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [testCell alloc] init...
}
```

Your classname `testCell` should start with an uppercase letter, use `TestCell` instead.